# Using simple instance as parameter to a c legacy function

Tags: c++

I have defined a helper class for a 4*4 matrix:

```
class BCMatrix {
  public:
    float matrix[4][4];

  void do_something_nice();
  void do_something_else();
};
```

I have another function that comes from a C library and can not
be altered:

```
void copy_m4_m4(float r[4][4], float f[4][4]);
```

With my BCMatrix class i can do something like this:

```
float mat[4][4];
BCMatrix obmat;
copy_m4_m4(obmat.matrix, mat);
```

But i actually want to be able to do something like this:

```
BCMatrix mat;
BCMatrix obmat;
copy_m4_m4(obmat, mat);
```

Of course i could add an operator= or a simple function like this:

```
void copy_m4_m4(BCMatrix &to, BCMatrix &from)
{
    copy_m4_m4(t.matrix, f.matrix);
}
```

But i wonder if there is any elegant (correct and pleasant) way to tell the compiler that BCMatrix is actually just a float[4][4] with some extra methods, so that it can be directly used as a parameter to the copy_m4_m4() function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an implicit conversion operator, like the following. See [user-defined conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) for more details.

```
class BCMatrix {
public:
  using float_t = float[4];  // Typedef required because of array
  operator float_t*() { return matrix; } // The conversion operator itself

    float matrix[4][4];

  void do_something_nice();
  void do_something_else();
};

// Mock, to make sure it's working as planned
void copy_m4_m4(float r[4][4], float f[4][4]) {
  for(auto i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    for(auto j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
      std::cout << r[i][j] << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  std::string testString = "testing";

  // Test: fill the source array
  BCMatrix obmat;
  for(auto i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    for(auto j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
      obmat[i][j] = 5 * i * j;
    }
  }

  // Final step in proving it works: call the [4][4] function
  BCMatrix mat;
  copy_m4_m4(obmat, mat);
}
```

Comment: yes, that worked fine. I wonder though when i want to init the BCMatrix from a float mat[4][4] OR from another BCMatrix object, then i still need to defined 2 methods  init(BCMatrix &mat) and init(float mat[4][4]) ?

Comment: You'll need three constructors. Two copy constructors `BCMatrix(BCMatrix& mat)` and `BCMatrix(float mat[4][4])`. Because you're adding those, C++ requires you to write your own default constructor `BCMatrix()`.